# Do quantum events depend on the presence of observer?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, double-slit-experiment, measurement-problem, observers, schroedingers-cat

Similar to that in the Schrodinger's cat thought experiment the cat remains in superposition unless observed by an observer, also in the double slit experiment an electron is passing through both the slits until we observe one of it. Therefore, does an observer make significance in the outcome of quantum events.

Comment: Hi Ajinkya, your title imo, does not reflect your question, by the "state of observer", instead do you mean the "presence of an observer".  Also, I think there will be lots of duplicates of this question, the answer to  which really depends on which interpretation of QM you find most persuasive.   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpretations_of_quantum_mechanics

Comment: yes I tried searching the sites but didnt found any duplicates.

Answer (score 3):

The answer is ultimately yes, but the definition of observer in quantum mechanics is counterintuitively far from its colloquial definition, which is typically taken as "some conscious entity that does not interfere with a process." Instead, a quantum-mechanical observer is anything that *interacts* with a quantum system in such a way as to extract information from that system.

When you substitute the quantum-mechanical definition of observer in your statement, it reads: "Quantum systems are influenced by things that interact with them," which is now obviously true.

Comment: This answer is good but it leaves out an important point. Interaction with the environment (i.e. decoherence) explains why the system's density matrix diagonalizes, but it *doesn't* explain why we see one of the possible results represented by the diagonal terms in that density matrix.

Comment: It means that the Standard Quantum Results are always the same, but is breached in different ways for different observers, the observers would not influence the outcome or the effects caused due to Quantum Events.

Comment: @AjinkyaNaik Not entirely sure how you got that from my answer...

Comment: I dont know but your answer didnt satisfied me, how can an observer interact with Quantum Systems and change its results

Comment: I meant to say consciousness cannot change the outcomes of Quantum Events.

Comment: @AjinkyaNaik Observer wants to find out where an electron is, so they hit it with a photon.

Comment: @AjinkyaNaik Consciousness is not a well-defined concept, and therefore has no place in this Stack Exchange. See the Cognitive Science Stack Exchange for more information.

Comment: but if we were to find out an electron there is no need to hit it with a photon, isnt it already reflecting light?